# Warning while using Disk Utility to verify permissions on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, disk-utility

I was using Disk Utility to do a "Verify Permission" and I got the following message:

> Warning: SUID file
>   "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/ARDAgent"
>   has been modified and will not be
>   repaired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known issue, and actually a bogus message.

It has been around since Mac OS X 10.5, and while it has changed for Mac OS X 10.6, the issue still arises...

"You can safely ignore this message. It is accurate, but not a cause for concern." 
(Apple Support 2007-11-06 — Document No. 306925)

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1448

Warning: SUID file "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/ARDAgent" has been modified and will not be repaired.

Resolution
You can safely ignore these messages. You can also usually ignore any "ACL found but not expected..." message. These messages can occur if you change permissions on a file or directory. These messages are accurate but are generally not a cause for concern.